# Can't configure laravel Hyn/multi-tenant

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

Hi I am trying to migrate my application to Laravel hyb/multi-tenant as shown in the diagram. 
[image: The whole thing I am trying to achieve is shown here which will minimize length of post]

I have followed the tutorial by Ashok Gelal (https://medium.com/@ashokgelal/a-full-featured-multi-tenant-app-with-laravel-part-1-4049a3cc229d) all the steps.

I can, through command line CreateTenant which nicely posts the new hostnhame (in this case test1.abcd.com), creates new UUID, insert the user in the UUID db created automatically i.e. in users table as well as creation of roles and permissions using the spatie/laravel-permission package. I receive email of successful user creation and link for activation. I have configured the middleware EnforceTenancy as suggested

The problems are:

1. I just cant see the landing page test1.abcd.com.
2. When I click the email activation link I cant reach the page although I see the url correctly configured i.e. `http://test1.abcd.com/password/reset/eab60f6e968008f0b73b......`
3. How to configure more tenant databases is it correct that all such connections use 'tenant' as the connection name but different database names, db_username, and db_password etc.

Since I am unable to see the landing page, I am unable to test it

Comment: What are your application logs saying? I'd expect some exceptions there if the visited URLs remain blank.

Comment: My application logs are blank and so the same at artisan command line. The browser message is unable connect to site

Comment: I seem to have solved as many important steps, necessary for using localhost need changes. After that I am able to login and the dashboard.  These changes should have been mentioned in the popular tutorials posted everywhere.  I am still need to be clear whether the 'tenant' as connection name can be repeated for as many db we set up.